# Can't access to phpBB admin after fresh install on a CentOS server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos6, phpbb3

After a fresh install straight I can login to the admin, but when I logout and try to login back I can't.

No problem to login anytime to the board, to the users interface... When I click on `Administration Control Panel` always I got a black white screen with an error message:

> Forbidden | You don't have permission to access /adm/index.php on this
>   server.

Also do the same if I type the right admin url: http://www.example.com/adm/index.php. Something wrong with the server options? How can be fix that issue?

Give a same error message if I try to run a `phpinfo.php` as well... (phpBB's phpinfo is working and show me the details...)

Centos6, Cgi/FastCgi, php5.4 & php5.5 (PHP Selector), SeLinux disabled, File permissions is 644 & 755.

Comment: could be a directory before doesn't have the correct permissions.. if its served from /var/www/html/some/path  all of those need to have the correct permissions for the web/php user to get into

Comment: It served from /home/username01/public_html/. The home directory owned by root and the username01 with public_html by username01 who is web/php user. user folder set to 755, username01 folder set to 711, public_html folder set to 755. I tried set username01 folder to 755 but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modsecurity are enabled and that is blocked the access. Have to enable the access by own rules on the settings...